# Parse url with API to an array via simple html dom parser

Tags: php, parsing

I have a problem with starting a project of 'clan community statistics'.
I have a [URL](http://api.worldoftanks.eu/2.0/clan/info/?application_id=d0a293dc77667c9328783d489c8cef73&clan_id=500000001) with the API of the statistics, and i want to show this in an array using a **simple html dom parser**. I want to get this effect:

```
{
  "status": "ok", 
  "count": 1, 
  "data": {
    "1": {
      "members_count": 100, 
      "description": "Закрытый клан...", 
      "description_html": "<p>Закрытый клан....\n</p>", 
      "created_at": 1293024672, 
      "updated_at": 1375930001, 
      "name": "Wargaming.net", 
      "abbreviation": "WG", 
      "emblems": {
        "large": "http://cw.worldoftanks.ru/media/clans/emblems/clans_1/1/emblem_64x64.png", 
        "small": "http://cw.worldoftanks.ru/media/clans/emblems/clans_1/1/emblem_24x24.png", 
        "medium": "http://cw.worldoftanks.ru/media/clans/emblems/clans_1/1/emblem_32x32.png", 
        "bw_tank": "http://cw.worldoftanks.ru/media/clans/emblems/clans_1/1/emblem_64x64_tank.png"
      }, 
      "clan_id": 1, 
      "members": {
        "196632": {
          "created_at": 1293126248, 
          "role": "private", 
          "updated_at": 1375930001, 
          "account_id": 196632, 
          "account_name": "Wrobel"
        }, 
        "18458": {
          "created_at": 1360836543, 
          "role": "diplomat", 
          "updated_at": 1375930001, 
          "account_id": 18458, 
          "account_name": "alienraven"
        }, 
        "3100": { ....
        }
      }, 
      "motto": "Орлы! Орлицы!", 
      "clan_color": "#e18000", 
      "owner_id": 1277137
    }
  }
}
```

My code

```
include('simple_html_dom.php');
$html = file_get_html('http://api.worldoftanks.eu/2.0/clan/info/?application_id=d0a293dc77667c9328783d489c8cef73&clan_id=500009659');
...?
```

What should I do next to prepare an array and display it in the way which I want on my web page? Is there someone obliging to explain it to me? please.

Greetings Mary

Answer (score -1):

I see the data is in json format. Just use:

```
$json  =  file_get_contents('http://api.worldoftanks.eu/2.0/clan/info/?application_id=d0a293dc77667c9328783d489c8cef73&clan_id=500009659'); //gets the json
$obj = json_decode($json); //decode the json into object or array. You'll get an object
var_dump($obj); //view the object. Parse the object the way you want to.
```

Answer (score -1):

try this

```
<?php
// example of how to modify HTML contents
include('../simple_html_dom.php');

// get DOM from URL or file
$html = file_get_html('http://api.worldoftanks.eu/2.0/clan/info/?application_id=d0a293dc77667c9328783d489c8cef73&clan_id=500009659');

$data = json_decode($html);

echo "<pre>";
print_r($data);
?>
```